# How do I plot predicted probabilities for a Logit regression with fixed effects in R?

Tags: r, plot, logistic-regression, predict, confidence-interval

I am a complete newbie to R.

I have the following logit equation I am estimating:

```
allAM <- glm (AM ~ VS + Prom + LS_Exp + Sex + Age + Age2 + Jpart + X2004LS + X2009LS + X2014LS + factor(State), family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = mydata)
```

AM is a standard binary (happened/didn’t happen). The three “X****LS” variables are dummies indicating different sessions of congress and “factor(State)” is used to generate fixed effects/dummies for each state.

VS is the key independent variable of interest and I want to generate the predicated probability that AM=1 for each value of VS between 0 and 60, holding everything else at its mean.

I am running into trouble, however, generating and plotting the predicted probabilities because “State” is a factor.  I want to be able to show the average effects, not 50 different charts/effects for each state.

Per (Hanmer and Kalkan 2013) http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1540-5907.2012.00602.x/abstract I was advised to do the following to plot the predicted probabilities:

```
pred.seq <- seq(from=0, to=60, by=0.01)

pred.out <- c()

for(i in 1:length(pred.seq)){

mydata.c <- mydata

mydata.c$VS <- pred.seq[i]

pred.out[i] <- mean(predict(allAM, newdata=mydata.c, type="response"))

}

plot(pred.out ~ pred.seq, type="l")
```

This approach seems to work, though I don’t really understand it.

I want to add the upper and lower 95% confidence intervals to the plot, but when I attempt to do it by hand the way I know how:

```
lower <- pred.out$fit - (1.96*pred.out$se.fit)
upper <- pred.out$fit + (1.96*pred.out$se.fit)
```

I get the following error:

Error in pred.outfit:fit: operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Can anyone advise how I can plot the confidence intervals and how I can specify different levels of VS so that I can report some specific predicted probabilities?

Comment: I think you're getting that error message because you didn't include `se.fit = TRUE` in the call to `predict`. See if adding that works.